# overflow: hidden with relative parent not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, overflow, parent, hidden

[I want to make my work look like this][1]
[But my work is now like this][2]

The vertical grey line is the web border, all other divs' width would not exceed that line.

Now users might drag and see the rest of the image. It would be much better if the exceeded part of the image is hidden.

So here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="container-div">
   <img class="the-img" src="image.png" alt="">
</div>
```

css:

```
.container-div {
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.the-img {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-left: -75.5vw;
}
```

Also, all the parent div of `.container-div` in my exact code are already `position: relative;`

How do I fix this? Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glA2q.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcBpO.png

Comment: Oops, sorry for the bad placement of links lol.

Comment: what is the `width` *.container-div*?

Comment: overflow:hidden on the parent not the child

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have tried doing so, but the whole image just disappear from my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `overflow: hidden` on the `.container-div`?

Comment: Yes I did. The whole image just disappear from my screen. Not sure why. :(

Comment: The image area is still highlighted in inspect when I hover the <img> tag, but the image is not showing up.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, this post seems more like a comment than a real answer. Next time, please use the comment function and only answer if you're sure!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should put `overflow: hidden` on the parent element.
Then you should set a height to it, your browser can't set a correct height on the parent element because its child doesn't have any (because of absolute position).

```
.container-div {
        text-align: right;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:200px;
    }

    .the-img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 1vh;
        margin-left: -75.5vw;
    }
```